# Set axis domain dynamically based on minimum and maximum dataset value for a d3.js bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I am trying to assign a dynamic domain values for `d3.js` bubble chart. I am creating bubbles for total amount for an error per client. When I use a hardcoded range, I see the bubbles for each client. I have a working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/02skzw4p/6/).

```
.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 30]))
.y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 30]))
.r(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 250]))
```

But, when I change these to minimum and maximum that i calculate using `d3.extent` then it doesn't work.

```
var minMax = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    if (d.status == "settlement error") {
      return d.amount;
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the minimum and maximum is calculated for an error type but not for an aggregated amount.

Here is my simplified data:

```
id,client,date,amount,status
10003,chase,2023-02-01,8,settlement error
10007,bofa,2022-11-22,2,settlement error
10008,citi,2022-11-22,8,settlement error
10009,chase,2023-02-01,4,settlement error
```

This should translate into:

```
chase - error count = 2, total amount = 12
bofa - error count = 1, total amount = 2
citi - error count = 1, total amount = 8
```

But, if you see the data, the minimum amount is 2, and maximum amount is 8. That is what my `minMax` value is set to `[2,8]`. Instead I want `[2,12]` for better plotting. Even better if I can get some padding like `[1,15]`.

**Edit**
After @pernifloss gave a solution which somehow didn't solve my issue, I tried to take a different route where I added `custom_elastic` where I am trying to get the min and max from my dimension but `var max = clientErrorChart.dimension().top[1][0].value;` errors:

```
function custom_elastic(clientErrorChart) {
    var max = 300;//clientErrorChart.dimension().top[1][0].value;
    var min = 10;//clientErrorChart.dimension().top(10)[9].value;
    clientErrorChart.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max]))
}
```

Then, I added this to my chart's `preRender` and `preRedraw` event.

```
clientErrorChart
    .height(300)
    .dimension(clientDim)
    .group(errorsByClient)
    .transitionDuration(1500)
    .colors(colorScale)
    //.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 3000]))
    .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 3000]))
    .r(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 250]))
    .keyAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.payment_sum;
    })
    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.count;
    })
    .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.error_count;
    })
    .transitionDuration(1500)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxisPadding(1)
    .xAxisPadding(1)
    .label(function (p) {
        return p.key;
    })
    .renderLabel(true)
    .renderTitle(true)
    .title(p => [
        p.key,
        `Total Error: ${formatNumber(p.value.error_count)}`,
        `Total Payment: ${formatNumber(p.value.payment_sum)}`,
        `Total Volume: ${formatNumber(p.value.count)}`          
    ].join('\n')); 

clientErrorChart.on('preRender', custom_elastic)
    .on('preRedraw', custom_elastic);
```

Answer (score 0):

`minMax` is just an array of 2 values, `[2,8]`, if you want to remove to min and add max, you can simply do

```
minMax = [ minMax[0] - 2 , minMax[1] + 7 ];
```

Or generate it anyway you want

Comment: The problem is that `minMax` is not calculating the right range. it gets `[2,8]` which is minimum and maximum values of the entire dataset. I want it should take the minimum and maximum after aggregating the amount by client. In example above it would be `[2,12]`. I can subtract/add to array elements to increase the range, but first I have to fix the actual values in `minMax[0]` and `minMax[1]`. How to calculate that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question then I add another answer with a way to calculate min max grouped

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reduce to aggregate and sum your data

```
var sumAmountGroupByClient = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  const found = a.find(d => d.client === b.client);
  if (found) {
    return a.map(v => v.client === b.client ? {
      client: v.client,
      sum: v.sum + b.amount
    } : v);
  }
  return [...a, {
    client: b.client,
    sum: b.amount
  }]
}, []);
var minMax = d3.extent(sumAmountGroupByClient.map(d => d.sum));
```

```js
data = [{
    "id": "    10003",
    "client": "chase",
    "date": "2023-02-01",
    "amount": 8,
    "status": "settlement error",
    "count": null,
    "dd": "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "    10007",
    "client": "bofa",
    "date": "2022-11-22",
    "amount": 2,
    "status": "settlement error",
    "count": null,
    "dd": "2022-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "    10008",
    "client": "citi",
    "date": "2022-11-22",
    "amount": 8,
    "status": "settlement error",
    "count": null,
    "dd": "2022-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "    10009",
    "client": "chase",
    "date": "2023-02-01",
    "amount": 4,
    "status": "settlement error",
    "count": null,
    "dd": "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
]


var sumAmountGroupByClient = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  const found = a.find(d => d.client === b.client);
  if (found) {
    return a.map(v => v.client === b.client ? {
      client: v.client,
      sum: v.sum + b.amount
    } : v);
  }
  return [...a, {
    client: b.client,
    sum: b.amount
  }]
}, []);
var minMax = d3.extent(sumAmountGroupByClient.map(d => d.sum));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This is nice, but in my original example (fiddle) I have `crossfilter`, how to replace `data` with `clientDim.group()` to work with filtered data.

Comment: I am not sure if my previous comment made sense, I mean this code is using `data.reduce((a, b)` which will work on the entire data. But, if user clicks on other charts to filter, the range won't be the same anymore. So, instead I want `sumAmountGroupByClient` method works with filtered data and not on the whole data set. Can that be done, otherwise the bubbles won't show up.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't understand your code. I can't even find which variable contains your filtered data.

Comment: I am not sure if you can see my working example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/02skzw4p/6/
I am using `clientDim` in my chart `clientErrorChart`.

Comment: And this https://jsfiddle.net/5w6shje3/1/ is not the behavior you want?

Comment: I have also added an update to my OP that shows an alternate way to get `min` and `max` from the dimension itself, of course it doesn't work but this solution is very close to what I am looking for. If you can help with how to get min and max from my dimension